# OrientDB order by not working

Tags: orientdb

In my OrientDB environment the ORDER BY clause is not working.

I do a simple query at the console:

> select from batchjob order by mode

And I get this exception:

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OResponseProcessingException: Exception during response processing

Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerImpl

I am running orientDB version 17. This fails on all my entities and on any field. My 'batchjob' entity is a simple one with a few string fields like 'mode'. I have had no other issues and have extensively with this environment.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: OrientDB 1.7 is about 3 years old and not supported long time ago. Please use 2.2.x.

Comment: OK thanks will try now.

Comment: When I login via the console it says: OrientDB console v.2.2.11 (build 2.2.x@r8b3a478e3ca7321a48e7cf0f5991569bbe06ed89; 2016-10-03 09:39:41+0000). When I do info I see: |0   |Version          |17 . I used an Amazon AMI that says this is version 2.2. How can I tell and how do I upgrade if needed? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The latest version is 2.2.14 as now

Comment: The point is am I on version 2.2 or 17 and why can't I use Order By? On the console and I use the command 'Info' I get version 17 , yet when I login to the console I get version 2.2  --- All I want to is know why I can't use the Order by command!

Answer (score 1):

I found something interesting even with 2.2.21.

I needed to use the alias instead of the column name to get `ORDER BY` working.

Ex: The following is not working.

`select a.name, a.age from (match {class: Person, as: a} return a) order by a.age`

But this works

`select a.name, a.age as age from (match {class: Person, as: a} return a) order by age`

I think unlike in sql `a` is not visible after the results are fetched and before the sorting is done.